# Adding custom request header to every API in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, header, request-headers

I am trying to add custom request header to every API I can do it by adding a piece of code  to every API

```
`public ResponseDTO setNames(@RequestHeader(value="my-header",required = false HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception {}`
```

But I want this to be done automatically like we have authorisation header by default when we create a new API.How can this be done can anyone tell me a good solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kSR3.png)

Comment: Do you want to add documentation to your API or use the header to make some validations in every API?

Comment: I want to do validation in every api

Comment: **Solved** Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73503791/10063334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following if you are using `springdoc-openapi`

```kotlin
@Configuration
class CustomizeSpringDoc {
    @Bean
    fun publicApi(): GroupedOpenApi {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("add-auth-header")
            .addOperationCustomizer { operation, handlerMethod ->
                operation.parameters.add(
                    HeaderParameter()
                        .name("Authorization")
                        .description("Access Token")
                )
                operation
            }
            .build()
    }
}
```

If you are using `spring-fox`, you can refer back to the below link, `globalRequestParameters`:
http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#quick-start-guides

Answer (score 2):

For making header validation for each request, you can use a `Filter` or `HandlerInterceptors`.

`Filters` intercept requests before they reach the `DispatcherServlet`, making them ideal for coarse-grained tasks such as:

- Authentication
- Logging and auditing
- Image and data compression
- Any functionality we want to be decoupled from Spring MVC

`HandlerIntercepors`, on the other hand, intercepts requests between the `DispatcherServlet` and our `Controllers`. This is done within the Spring MVC framework, providing access to the Handler and ModelAndView objects.

This reduces duplication and allows for more fine-grained functionality such as:

- Handling cross-cutting concerns such as application logging
- Detailed authorization checks
- Manipulating the Spring context or model

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor-vs-filter

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `java` version of the Kotlin answer

```java
@Bean
GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
        .group("add-user-id-header")
        .addOperationCustomizer((operation, $) -> {
            operation.addParametersItem(
                new HeaderParameter()
                    .name("Authorization")
                    .description("Access Token")
                    .required(true)
            );
            return operation;
        })
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `OpenAPI specification (previously Swagger specification)` in your Spring-boot project, where in , you define your APIs along with `Request/Response` headers as well as any error model you may want to return or any other custom field you want to capture!

By defining, you will have privilege of mentioning attributes such as `required, minLength, maxLength` etc

The openAPI plugin will take care of rest of the things!

***You may refer these links to have a glance!***

https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_swagger3

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation